# JTextBox always has newline

Tags: java, swing, events, networking, interface

I'm building a chat program. The user has the option to press a JButton SEND or just press ENTER on the keyboard to send the message. This is my code.

```
private void chatTextAreaKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

            this.sendButtonActionPerformed(null);
            this.chatTextArea.setText(null); // Clear JTextBox
        }
    }
```

The problem with this, is that after pressing ENTER, it sets the JTextBox with a empty new line. So that whatever I type next will always be on the second line instead of starting with an empty text box.

Anyone has any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not setting the text to empty string `""`?

Comment: *"..it sets the JTextBox"*  No such thing.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: setText("") has the same outcome as (null)

Comment: Presumably you mean `JTextField`?

Comment: btw: don't use KeyListeners, instead use keyBindings ... which would have taken care of the consume auto-magically :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consume the event with [`evt.consume()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume%28%29) to ensure it isn't processed by the text field itself.

This indicates that all processing of the event has finished and no other listeners should act upon the event.

Comment: IMHO- This is a bad idea.  Firstly, `KeyListener` does not support pasting from the clipboard, secondly, we've actually yet to figure out what type of field the user is actually using. If they are using a `JTextField` this will be taken care of by the `ActionListener`, if a `JTextArea` it would be better to use the key bindings API.  By the time that the `KeyListener` is notified, the key stroke may already have been sent to the document under different look and feels and platforms